# How to play redirected m3u8 stream on kodi/xbmc?

Tags: php, redirect, xbmc, m3u8, kodi

I am having issues with playing redirected .m3u8 streams in XBMC/kodi. I have the following php script that i call it like this :

```
http://www.MyWebsite.com/getStream.php?channel=12
```

if i use the above link in kodi/xbmc it never plays it ! could any one tell me how to fix this issue and allow xbmc/kodi to play links like above? Should i add extra header?

```
<?

//rest of code that gets the actual stream url
$a="http://someRemoteWebsite.com/hls/stream12.m3u8?token=234324213243";
header("Location: " . $a);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It will not play a url like that unless its in an addon and knows to be redirected to the raw m3u8.  If you are plopping the http://www.MyWebsite.com/getStream.php?channel=12 into a strm file it tries to play http://www.MyWebsite.com/getStream.php?channel=12 as videos and since it is not it fails.